# How do I remove a specific leaf node with index value X and display the remaining leaf nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

Test case:

Input:

```
5
-1 0 0 1 1
2
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJvCB.png]

Output:

```
2
```

Explanation:

The tree corresponding to the numeric input is shown above. Initially, there are 3 leaves, 2, 3 and 4 (marked green). If we delete node 2, then two leaves are left, i.e., 3 and 4. Hence, the answer is 2.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJvCB.png]

Another test case:

Input:

```
5
-1 0 0 1 1
1
```

Output:

```
1
```

Explanation:

After deleting node 1, the only remaining leaf is 2.

Comment: not the greatest explanation of the problem ;) If we delete 3 and 4 what will be the answer? I guess 2 again - leaves 1 and 2 right?

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I have added an example. :)

Comment: one thing I realized is the values of the nodes doesn't matter, its just its node index that has to be taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create tree-structure from your input. Each node has this values: `node = { value, leftChild, rightChild }`

```
function trace(node, deletedValue) {
  if (!node){
     return; // nothing to see there
  }

  if (node.value === deletedValue) {
     return; // this one is deleted, do not continue
  }

  if (!node.leftChild && !node.rightChild){
     console.log(node.value); //found not deleted leaf
     return;
  }

  trace(node.leftChild);
  trace(node.rightChild);
}
```